# redirect_to show page instead update in controller? rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

am doing redirecting in my controller action something like this

```
format.html { redirect_to product_path(@product) }
```

which is taking me to `PUT /products/123456`

but i would like to go `GET /products/123456`.
can some explain me why this is happening. what is the exact helper method should i use to go with GET request?

According to doc `product_path(@product)` is comon for all `GET, PUT/PATCH`, and `DELETE.`

I could not find any option to pass something like

```
format.html { redirect_to product_path(@product) }, method: :get
```

in `redirect_to` api doc. Please explain me how can i achieve this. thanks

**Update:**

```
def delete_product_media
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  @product_media = ProductMedium.where(id: params[:product_media_ids])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @product_media.update_all(deleted_at: Time.zone.now) == params[:product_media_ids].count
      flash[:notice] = 'Media deleted'
      flash.keep(:notice)
      format.html { redirect_to product_path(@product), method: :get }
    else
      flash[:notice] = 'Something went wrong!'
      flash.keep(:notice)
      format.html {redirect_to product_path(@product) }
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: can you post little bit more code of your action ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A redirect with `redirect_to` (default HTTP `302 Found`) which should persist the method, allthough does not always. You can use `303 See Other` if you want to force a `GET`.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302

> Even if the specification requires the method, and the body, not to be altered when the redirection is performed, not all user-agents conform here, and you can still find buggy software out there. It is therefore recommended to set the 302 code only as a response for GET or HEAD methods and to use 307 Temporary Redirect instead, as the method change is explicitly prohibited in that case.
>
> In the cases where you want the method used to be changed to GET, use 303 See Also instead. This is useful when you want to give an answer to a PUT method that is not the uploaded resource, but a confirmation message (like "You successfully uploaded XYZ").

For `redirect_to` the `status` option overrides the default, e.g. `redirect_to product_path(@product), status: :see_other`.

Comment: Thanks. That's a clear explanation. I used status 303, which is redirecting me to show page. But here one more issue am facing, am calling the above action in a AJAX call from show page, after action am returning back to show page with updated data. But page not getting refreshed. Any clue how to solve this?

Comment: If you just "submit" a `<form>` you will get normal page reloads. AJAX is designed to not reload the page ever, it just gives you the response data to deal with in JavaScript. In JavaScript you can use [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) to reload as a `GET`, or use a hidden form to get `POST` (and under Rails `PUT`, `DELETE`, etc. via its special `_method` form parameter). HTTP redirects use the `Location` header so you can retrieve that in JavaScript (but be sure to check for 4XX or 5XX error response as well!)

Comment: Thank you. am already doing window.location.reload. it reloading after a fraction of seconds when user clicking delete button(because it waiting for ajax call to finish executing :(. Okay. any how thanks

Answer (score -1):

You could do `redirect_to @products` if you want to redirect to show page . Which will be processed like GET /products/123456 .